# Make Web3Client url have metamask connection in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, blockchain, web3dart

```
  Client httpClient = Client();
  late Web3Client scClient;
  SmartContractUniSwap() {
    scClient = Web3Client(
        'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/f847d455fefb4a4580017cb031b35442',
        httpClient);
  }
```

This is the code to create a Web3Client but it needs a node( like Infuria node) url, i'm having a wallet_connect session( from wallet_connect_dart) and i want to use web3dart package to send transactions having the data of smart contract collected from the web3dart. How can i do that?